# Listening to network traffic on specific port JAVA

Tags: java, networking, tcp

How do i sniff network packets like wireshark does on a range of ports? E.g. 5000-5500. In Wireshark i can specify the type e.g. tcp portrange 5000-5500.
I've worked with sockets in java, but it doesn't seem to fulfil this. Anyone who knows how to tackle this problem?

E.g. i'd like to know the packet length (bytes), the source and destination port and the window size value.

What's the better approach?

Comment: The better approach is not to try to use Java for something like this.

Comment: You have to get access to raw packets without consuming them. That's not something you can do with Sockets. Take a look at the jnetpcap wrapper for pcap.

Comment: @Kayaman what then?

Comment: @alexanderson Why do you want to sniff packets? Are you trying to make a Java wireshark? There's no way you can achieve that without native code, and then you'll just have a crappy copy of wireshark written in Java.

Comment: @kayaman no i'm interested in knowing when a specific message is sent to my computer so that i can respond with an action to that.

Comment: @alexanderson Then why aren't you using regular socket communication? Sniffing packets is not something you use instead of normal sockets.